# Python for loop over json data throws 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' only when a single element of data

Tags: python, json

I've inherited the following code which is working great, apart from when only a single data item is return from the original xml. When that occurs the following error is thrown: 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

```
 result = xmltodict.parse(get_xml())

 latest_result = result['Response']['Items']['Item']
 myJsonData = json.dumps(latest_result)

 j=  json.loads(myJason)
 print type(j)

 for item in j:
    print (item['Id'])
    print (item['OrderId'])
```

I have narrowed the change in behaviour to a difference in datatype here:

```
print type(j)
```

When only a single ['Item'] is returned from the source XML the datatype of j is a 'dict', whilst the rest of the time (greater than one ['Item']) its a 'list'.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: You can omit the `json.dumps()` / `json.loads()` here (and use `latest_result` rather than `j`), it has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding to JSON then decoding again has nothing to do with your question. It is a red herring, you can use `latest_result` and still get the same error.

The `result['Response']['Items']['Item']` can evidently be either a list of dictionaries, or a single dictionary. When iterating over a list, you'll get contained elements, while iteration over a dictionary gives you the keys. So your `item` elements are strings (each a key in the dictionary) and you can't address elements in that string with `'Id'` or `'OrderId'`.

Test for the type or use exception handling:

```
if isinstance(latest_result, dict):
    # just one result, wrap it in a single-element list
    latest_result = [latest_result]
```

Alternatively, fix up the `xmltodict` code (which you didn't share or otherwise identify) to always return lists for elements, even when there is just a single one.

Comment: Thanks, your solution using the test is perfect for my example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common `xmltodict` module usage problem. When there is a single child, by default, it makes a `dict` out of it and not a list with a single item. Relevant github issue:

- [xml containing 1 child](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/14)

To workaround it, one option would be to set the `dict_constructor` argument:

```
from collections import defaultdict

xmltodict.parse(xml, dict_constructor=lambda *args, **kwargs: defaultdict(list, *args, **kwargs))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are correct as a researched the issue you highlighted with xmltodict. In this example i decided to use the test as described by Martin Peters above. Simply because I am not familiar with the dict_constructor.